# How to setup nginx with docker to work from outside local network

Tags: nginx, docker

I've a Synology nas that are using docker, I use nginx and php on it. 
I can connect to my website if I connect to it with its port number,
but what I want is not to use an port number to reach it from outside.

So my question is how do I connect to it without the port number or how would I host my website so I could connect it to as www.mydomain.com?

**Local network** - 10.0.1.15:8080  (Works)

**Public network** xxx.xxx.xxx:8080 (Works)

**Config file:**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html/public;
    index index.html index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
nginx:
    build: ./nginx/
    ports:
        - 8080:80
    links:
        - php
    volumes_from:
        - app

php:
    build: ./php/
    expose:
        - 9000
    links:
        - mysql
    volumes_from:
        - app


composer:
    image: composer/composer
    volumes_from: 
        - app

app:
    image: php:7.0-fpm
    volumes:
        - .:/var/www/html
    command: "true"



mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes_from:
        - data
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
        MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname
        MYSQL_USER: username
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: password

data:
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes:
        - /var/lib/mysql
    command: "true"



phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
        - 8888:80
    links:
        - mysql
    environment:
        PMA_HOST: mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

You are publishing your `nginx` on port `8080` on docker host. You should publish it on port `80` if its not already taken to be able to open `yourdomain.com` which defaults to port `80` on `http`.

Another option would be running another `nginx` container published on port `80` and `reverse proxy` to your different containers on different ports via http headers. this approach lets you host multiple websites on port `80` or `443` in separate containers on a docker host.

Example nginx Config:

```
  server {
      listen       80;
      server_name  somename1.yourdomain.com;

      location / {
        proxy_pass  http://nginxContainerName:8080;
      }
  server {
      listen       80;
      server_name  somename2.yourdomain.com;

      location / {
        proxy_pass  http://synologysContainerName:8081;
      }
  server {
      listen       80;
      server_name  somename3.yourdomain.com;

      location / {
        proxy_pass  http://phpmyadminContainername:8888;
      }
    }
```

Make sure you have you create a user defined network:

```
docker network create mynetwork
```

And you put all your containers in it.

Comment: The port 80 is already taken when I specify nginx to 80:80, by synology I guess because I get some standard synology screen when going to its localhost:80 .

Comment: publish that in another container on another port, then reverse proxy them all using the nginx reverse proxy container.

Comment: You mean the synologys port hosted by sonology port 80 should be changed?

Comment: Found this https://stefandingemanse.nl/configure-reverse-proxy-synology-nas-dsm-6-beta-2/ can I change this somehow

Comment: I mean change synologys port  to like 8081, then reverse proxy using nginx container

Comment: ahh okey so its here inside nginx.conf I should change?  `server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        listen 443 default_server ssl;
        listen [::]:443 default_server ssl;

        server_name _;

        location ~ ^/volume(?:X|USB|SATA|Gluster)?\d+/ { `

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks will try it out, but it is correct that I still need to change the port first as you said, and is it correct it is the nginx.conf holding the 80 port of my Synology?

Comment: Currently having problem remove /change my port 80 of synology it recreate it to port 80